# Display CSS loader and text on the same line

Tags: html, css, animation, markup

I have a custom CSS loader animation which I would like to display next to a text element on the same line, but so far I haven't managed it.

```css
#loader{
  display:none;
}

#loader.active{
  display:block;
}
.lds-ring {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.lds-ring div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 8px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: lds-ring 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.lds-ring div:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: -0.45s;
}

.lds-ring div:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}

.lds-ring div:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -0.15s;
}

@keyframes lds-ring {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="mytext"> LOADING </p>

<div id="loader">
  <div class="lds-ring">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I display the animation just to the right of my 'mytext' element on the same line?

Comment: set the loader aside your text and turn `<div id="loader">
  <div class="lds-ring">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>`  into inline-block spans `<span id="loader">
  <span class="lds-ring">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </span>
</span>`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/re9qzwan/ and a flex option to set at center could be : https://jsfiddle.net/sm9uw4rf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap both elements in a `div`, we'll give it a class name of 'flex':

```
<div className="flex">
      <p className="mytext"> LOADING </p>

      <div class="loader">
        <div class="lds-ring">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And then add this CSS property to that div:

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

That should align them as you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

`p` and `div` elements are `display: block;` by default by most browsers. To display them next to each other set `.mytext` and `#loader.active` `display` property to `inline-block`.

```
.mytext {
    display: inline-block;
}
#loader.active {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This will set them next to each other. You can also adjust the width of each using the `width`, `max-width`, or `min-width` properties. Use the `vertical-align` to align the elements top, middle, and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the code next to it and put in

```
<span id="loader-text">loading...</span>
```

instead of a big load of code.